Layer styles lost in QGIS 3.6.2
I have noticed when upgrading from QGIS 3.38 to 3.6.2 all styles change to a default style. For example all polygons turn blue. I have seen this in the past. Is this a bug and there a fix for this? It would be a big task to go through every project and revert the style back.

Is QGIS 3.6.2 a nightly build for developers? If so - this build may contain bugs. Try LTR (long term release) or the latest stable version: https://qgis.org/download/

Going from 3.38 to 3.6.2 seem more like downgrading are you sure of the version ?

If you typed the version number correctly, it is indeed a huge downgrade. Read the number after the decimal as an absolute value, not a fraction. Therefore, 38 >> 6.  The issue you are experiencing is likely caused by opening a project in an older version of QGIS than in which it was saved.

You are quite right. I've made that mistake before which is silly. I will get these users to upgrade to the latest in that case. Thanks and apologies for that error.
